# ConTeXt equivalent of LaTeX's \label and \refstepcounter?

Tags: context, counters

In LaTeX I can label anything provided that it is numbered with a referenceable counter. Moreover, references are automatically numbered with `\refstepcounter`. For instance, I write the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{lol}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Hola \refstepcounter{lol}\arabic{lol}\label{ha}
\item Chao
\item Mira \ref{ha}.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

How to do that in ConTeXt?

Comment: What is your goal? The reference mechanism in ConTeXt works different and labels are passed as argument to an environment (e.g. enumerations) or an command (e.g. items). You can also place your own labels but the don't refer to the last counter.

Comment: I want to define an environment with two or more counters. E.g. something like 15. Theorem IV. (references both to 15 and IV). Cite \in[item15] and \in[theorem4] with corresponding reference texts (Item 15 and Theorem IV).

Comment: Can you make a new question with a detailed description how the environment should work, especially how all counters should interact.